# VHDL state machine

Tags: vhdl

I wrote some code in VHDL that is expected to look at a rotory switch and feed back to me what position it is in.

When it gets turned it will read in the greycode from the rotor dial and switch states to the corresponding greycode state.

The act of changing states tells me which way the rotor is being twisted so I can indicate either an up or down state on a counter module later in the circuit.

If the state changes it should trigger a pulse on `Mag` and triger either a 1 or 0 on `up_dwn`.

It doesn't work when I simulate it.  I get an occassional blip on `Mag` but no `up_dwn` change.

I suspect it's stuck in the`START`state.

Anyone care to look and tell me what I've done wrong?

[Ed:  Using Quartus II Version 9 ]

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY EncoderV2    IS
PORT(
    CH_AB           :   IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
    clk             :   IN  STD_LOGIC;
    nReset          :   IN  STD_LOGIC;
    up_dwn, Mag     :   OUT STD_LOGIC);

    END EncoderV2;

ARCHITECTURE a OF EncoderV2 IS  --  
TYPE STATE_TYPE IS ( START, s00, s01, s11, s10);
SIGNAL state:   STATE_TYPE;

BEGIN
PROCESS (clk, nReset)
BEGIN
    IF nReset = '0' THEN                        --    asynch Reset to zero
        state   <=  START;
    ELSIF clk'EVENT AND clk = '1' THEN          --  triggers on PGT
        CASE state IS 
            WHEN START =>
                    IF CH_AB ="00" THEN
                                state   <= s00;
                                Mag <='0';
                    ELSIF CH_AB="01" THEN
                                state   <= s01;
                                Mag <='0';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "11" THEN
                                state   <= s11;
                                Mag <='0';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "10" THEN
                                state   <= s10;
                                Mag <='0';
                    ELSE  state <= START;
                    END IF;

            WHEN s00 =>                 --  S10 <- S00 -> S01
                    IF CH_AB= "00" THEN
                                state   <= s00;
                                Mag <='0';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "10" THEN
                                state   <= s10;
                                up_dwn  <= '0';
                                Mag <='1';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "01" THEN
                                state   <= s01;
                                up_dwn  <='1';
                                Mag <='1';
                    ELSE  state <= START;
                    END IF;

            WHEN s01 =>                 --  S00 <- S01 -> S11
                    IF CH_AB= "01" THEN
                                state   <= s01;
                                Mag <='0';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "00" THEN
                                state   <= s00;
                                up_dwn  <= '0';
                                Mag <='1';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "11" THEN
                                state   <= s11;
                                up_dwn  <='1';
                                Mag <='1';
                    ELSE state <= START;
                    END IF;

            WHEN s11 =>                 --  S01 <- S11 ->S10
                    IF CH_AB= "11" THEN
                                state   <= s11;
                                Mag <='0';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "01" THEN
                                state   <= s01;
                                up_dwn  <= '0';
                                Mag <='1';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "10" THEN
                                state   <= s10;
                                up_dwn  <='1';
                                Mag <='1';
                    ELSE state <= START;
                    END IF;

            WHEN s10 =>                 --  S11 <- S10 -> S00
                    IF CH_AB= "10" THEN
                                state   <= s10;
                                Mag <='0';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "11" THEN
                                state   <= s11;
                                up_dwn  <= '0';
                                Mag <='1';
                    ELSIF CH_AB= "00" THEN
                                state   <= s00;
                                up_dwn  <='1';
                                Mag <='1';
                    ELSE state <= START;
                    END IF;





            END CASE;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END a;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are stimulating your entity correctly? The behavior really depends on the inputs you're providing. If you're using Modelsim to simulate you should be able to see quiet easily where the problem is and where the actual behavior deviates from the expected one. The entity can't be stuck in the `START` state because `Mag` is always 0 in that state (you could replace all the `Mag<='0'` statements there by one single one before the first `IF`) and you say that `Mag` changes occasionally.

Comment: I'm using Quartus for the Sims and it seems as buggy as a Saskatchewan slew in August.  Now that I've been looking at it more I seem to have an input that won't change no matter what I set it too.  Starting to think the software migh be to blame.

Comment: Turns out the simulator is to blame.  The code all works just fine once I program it into the chip.  Seems to be an ongoing problem with Quartus.  Nice software, shame about the sim.

Comment: Shame. You could try simulating with Modelsim. There is a free student edition. It will limit the simulation speed after your code exceeds a certain number of lines but for your purposes it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: One advice on your synchronous process writing : `up_dwn` and `Mag` should be included in your reset clause (unless you have a specific reason not to do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works fine for me ... simulated with Modelsim

I simuleted it with 50, 100 and 200 MHz.
The only thing I wonder about is you use "IF .. nReset = '0' THEN" .. are you sure about it?
It cost me like 20minutes before I saw it and changed it in my stimulus file.

Comment: Guess I'm going to have to download ModelSim.  Weird that it works with that simulator but has buggy performance with Quartus. Same company I think.  nReset = '0' is correct.  Active low signal for all our Asynchronous resets is the rule in class.